# Are INTx pins the only ones eligible for Software Serial?

Tags: interrupt, softwareserial

As opposed to PCINT (Atmel's Pin Change INTerrupt, INTx is arduino-compatible interupt)  In other words, does Software Serial use atmel's pin change or arduino falling interrupt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SoftwareSerial` uses PCINT.  `AltSoftSerial` uses INT0 or INT1, which has FALLING, RISING, CHANGE or LOW LEVEL options.  See Section 12.2, p. 71 of the Atmel [ATmega328 spec](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc8161.pdf), for example.